# Custom list clicking with checkboxes

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, android-viewbinder

I've populated a `ListActivity` from a `Cursor` using `SimpleCursorAdapter` that starts another activity when one of the list items have been clicked.  I'm also using `ViewBinder` to do some custom transformation of the data.

I want to add a `CheckBox` to each row in the list so I've changed the view and added a `CheckBox` with gravity right.

Adding the `CheckBox` has removed the ability to click on the items.  The `onListItemClick` method I was overriding in `ListActivity` is no longer called when you press on a list item.  Removing the `CheckBox` fixes this.  Why is this?

Also, how can I set up the list so that it continues to perform my required functionality if the main part of the list item is clicked but have additional functionality when the `CheckBox` in the item is checked?  Will setting a `onCheckedChangedListener` work or is the same view instance reused for each item in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `SimpleCursorAdapter` is too primitive for what I wanted to achieve.
I've switched to implementing `CursorAdapter` and returning a new view using the `LayoutInflater` in my implementation of the `newView` method.

```
  public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.alarm_row, parent, false);
  }
```

In bindView I then set a custom `OnClickListener` to my main `LinearLayout` and then another `OnCheckedChangeListener` to the `CheckBox`.

For all this to look right I had to set the `LinearLayout`'s background to android's menuitem drawable:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/menuitem_background"
```

Answer (score 13):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121192/android-custom-listview-unable-to-click-on-items), the click listener only works if no other view is `focusable`. Setting your `CheckBox` to `focusable="false"` should do the trick:

```
<CheckBox android:focusable="false" />
```