# OnItemClick doesn't work with custom adapter

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener, custom-adapter

I have a `ListView` with `Custom Adapter`. I have seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571339/android-listview-setonitemclicklistener-not-registering-click-with-custom-adapte) where people asked if the items in the custom view had a clickable item. And Yes, I have a clickable `ImageView` in the `listrow`. So clicking anywhere else(other than that `ImageView`) should perform some other action. I gave an `onItemClickListener` to the `ListView`. However, it doesn't work on first click and works on two-three clicks.

Update:
In my adapter's getView method, I set onClick of ImageView like this:

```
holder.chatImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                            //Stuff here
                     }
        });
```

It works fine, and in my activity, I gave `onItemClickListener` to listView likw this:

```
onlineListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                //Stuff here

            }
        });
```

PS: I didn't explicitly give any focus to anything.

Comment: Maybe the you set a focus in the image? Post some code please

Comment: I use a custom Cursor adapter and button click is well differentiated from the list row click, all is working fine! Post some code..

Comment: I use a custom adapter, I usually only construct my view in the getView in my adapter. I implement the onlcick listener in my frag/activity where I will use the on click.. then override the onListItemClick() method.

Comment: have you tried use `convertView.setonclickListener` in getView method instead of `onlineListView.setOnItemClickListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I've faced the same problem but with a `CheckBox`, I've resolve it by creating a  `onClickListener` as member of the Custom Adapter. For example

```
public MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    // ... ..

    // ... ...

   private OnClickListener imageClickListener = new OnClickListener()
   {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
           /// your data .getTag()
           // process onClickListener for image
       }
   };

}
```

And then, in your `getView`:

```
if (convertView == null){
   //Create your views and register onClickListener
   holder.chatImageView.setOnClickListener(imageClickListener);

}
```

Add `android:focusable="false"` to your image in xml.

Hope it helps, Here you have the [entire example](http://elbauldelprogramador.com/adapter-personalizado-en-android/):

Comment: Tried this too. No change.

Comment: @SeshuVinay Add `android:focusable="false"` to your image in xml.