# list view loses clickable nature

Tags: android

I have a requirement that in a listview for every view i have to show textviews,imageview and a checkbox . but whenever if i add a checkbox to the listview then the listview loses its natural behaviour. i.e, it will not give any feedback if we click on listview.

instead I have tried by taking  images even for checkboxes also everything is ok now,but   `checkbox.ischecked()` methods so on.. can't be applied on images.

Can some one plz help out me in this issue ...

This is the layout i am using

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="#ffffff">


<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/chkfrnd2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_x="0px"
android:layout_y="0px"/>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/userimage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
</ImageView>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/userstatus"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/statusimage"
 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"  
>
</ImageView>
<RelativeLayout    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget48"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#000000"   
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15dip"   
        />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/userstatusmsg"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"   
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15dip"   
        android:text="TestMobileApp" />    
        </LinearLayout>
 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/userphone"
android:src="@drawable/newphone"  
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:clickable="true"
>
</ImageView>
<TextView android:id="@+id/friendstatus"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"   
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15dip"   
         />  
 </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

[ListView OnItemClickListener Not Responding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367936/listview-onitemclicklistener-not-responding)

Answer (score 0):

you must set the `focusable` attribute to false for your checkbox:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Your question has already been [answered on StackOverflow by @MattC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121192/android-custom-listview-unable-to-click-on-items).

Comment: Thanks rekaszeru , +1 for help..  Your answer is really helpful

Comment: no problem :) You should also be aware, that some other views, like the `ImageButton` and `RatingBar` do not respond for this trick, only if you set their focusable state from java code: `view.setFocusable(false)`.

Comment: Thanks for more imformation.HAve you any idea that i used checkbox in listview and when i select one checkbox other check also get selected in list

Comment: you probably use `findViewById` on the list, not the item's view. And since the checkboxes have the same id, all of them get selected. Didi you ask a question about this here? Please share it's link to see your source code. thanks.

Comment: have you asked a question already? please ask it, and share some source code as well, so we can help you :)