# How to use checkbox in listview (which have multilines in each list) and extends Listactivity?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, listactivity

this is my program which extends ListActivity and in each list I have multilines, picture and checkbox so I try like this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    List<Map<String, Object>> resourceNames =new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

    Map<String, Object> data1,data2;

    data1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();

      data1.put("line1", "adidas Chelsea Tee-Womens" );
      data1.put("line2", "$ 129.0" );
      data1.put("img", R.drawable.q1 );
      resourceNames.add(data1);
      data2.put("line1", "Chelsea Track Top-Womens" );
      data2.put("line2", "$ 399.0" );
      data2.put("img", R.drawable.q2 );
 resourceNames.add(data2);
SimpleAdapter notes = new SimpleAdapter(
        this,
        resourceNames,
        R.layout.row,
        new String[] {"line1","line2", "img" },
        new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.img } );
    setListAdapter(notes);
}
```

and I wonder how to get value from each checkbox in each list

this is my row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip">
<CheckBox 

android:id="@+id/checkBox1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></CheckBox>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

thanks.

Comment: what do you want to do when somebody clicks a listview item? have it put a check in the checkbox? or get processed by the OnItemSelectedListner?

Comment: get processed by the OnItemSelectedListner

Answer (score 1):

take a look here http://www.mousetech.com/blog/?p=74 and [Android custom ListView unable to click on items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121192/android-custom-listview-unable-to-click-on-items)

to summarize an already summarized blog, if a list item contains a focusable item, that item will get the click events.  so set the focusable attribute on the checkbox to false to prevent that from happening.