# How to handle multiple click in ListView?

Tags: android, event-handling

Is it possible to handle click of listview as well as its childview like checkbox in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution which can handle click for both list row as well as its child view. 
Refer this link.

[Android custom ListView unable to click on items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121192/android-custom-listview-unable-to-click-on-items)

I hope it will help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand it right, you want to have a Listview, where you can click on particular rows and also on checkboxes that are in this rows?!
Thats possible, you have to set OnClickListener/OnLongClickListener for the row clicks and an OnCheckedChangeListener for each checkbox.
Is that what you wanted?