# Android, how to redraw list when the user sets checkbox?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, redraw

I have a list view and each row contains two textviews and a checkbox.
I need user sets just one of checkboxes and if user sets other checkbox, previous checkbox should be cleared and second checkbox can be set.

I can generate the list but i don't know why `onListItemClick()` method does not work? therefore, I don't know which checkbox is set.

and my next question is, how can i redraw list after clicking checkbox by user?

my code is:

```
    package com.Infindo.DRM;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Infindo_PackageActivity extends ListActivity {

    private final String[] titels = {"Try before buy", "Pay per play", "Pay per day", "Pay per week", "Pay per month", "Daily subscription", "Weekly subscription", "Monthly subscription"};
    private final String[] descriptions = {"Free of charge", "Price: $1.00", "Price: $5.00", "Price: $10.00", "Price: $30.00", "Price: $5.00", "Price: $10.00", "Price: $30.00"};
    private String[] flag = {"false", "false", "false", "false", "false", "false", "false", "false"};
    private ListAdapter listAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.infindo_packagepage);

        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this);
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Log.i("List Clicked:", "******");
    }

    public void onCheckboxClicked(View v){
        int i = getSelectedItemPosition();
        Log.i("item pos:", String.valueOf(i)); // every time the result is -1???
    }


    //*********************
    //  RowModel Class
    //*********************
    private class RowModel{
        TextView title;
        TextView description;
        CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    //*********************
    //  ListAdapter Class
    //*********************
    private class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        public ListAdapter(Context c) {
            super(c, R.layout.infindo_listformat, titels);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            RowModel holder;
            View row = convertView;

            if(row == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infindo_listformat, parent, false);

                holder = new RowModel();
                holder.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
                holder.description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.description); 
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

                row.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (RowModel) row.getTag(); 
            }

            holder.title.setText(titels[position]);
            holder.description.setText(descriptions[position]);
            String s = flag[position];
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) 
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
            else
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);

            return(row);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I have added

```
@Override
        public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
            super.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.i("List Redrawed:", "**notifyDataSetChanged()**");
        }
```

into my List Adapter class and called it in

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View v){
        int i = getSelectedItemPosition();
        Log.i("item pos:", String.valueOf(i)); // every time the result is -1???
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I think the problem of redraw is solved. but I still I don't know what checkbox is clicked by the user in order to change flag array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` to know which checkbox was selected. You can look at complete example of ListView with CheckBox [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).

**UPDATE**

To make your `onListItemClick()` work you need to write `android:focusable="false"` for other items of the ListView, its because of the focus of other views ListView's `onListItemClick()` is not peforming as it should be performing.

Checkout this answer, why [Android custom ListView unable to click on items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121192/android-custom-listview-unable-to-click-on-items)

Comment: thanks dear Lalit, I saw that link before and it is so helpful. But my code is correct as well as that one you suggested. Just I don't know why "onListItemClick()" do not run in my code while will run in their code. I checked and compared my code with their code several times and everything seems OK, but this method does not run in my code. this is my question, why?

Comment: yes its because you have to add android:focusable="false" to other views in the ListView items, then listview's item click will work for you.

Comment: thanks dear Lalit. You are right. I added that line of code to all items of row and problem solved. Now, "onListItemClick()" works fine although i don't know what is the reason(s)?

Comment: Well you must know the reason, read the link that I had given you it will help you in future too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to handle the click from the checkbox itself and not just the listview.

Comment: Yes but in this situation, user should click checkbox. but if user clicks row instead of checkbox nothing will happen. It maybe not be important but Actually I need to know what checkbox is clicked. i think i need to know what is it's position in the list. I tried to find it in "onCheckboxClicked()" but for all checkboxes, the result is -1. I'm so confused and i don't know what and where is my mistakes?