# OnItemClickListener doesn't work with ListView item containing button

Tags: android, listview, button, adapter, onitemclicklistener

I have `ListView` with custom `Adapter` which supplies `View` to `ListView` in this way:

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
   {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lineParams;
        RelativeLayout line=new RelativeLayout(context);

        TextView tv=new TextView(context);
        tv.setText("Text in postion="+i);
        lineParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lineParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        line.addView(tv, lineParams);
        lineParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

        //checkbox
        CheckBox checkBox=new CheckBox(context);
        lineParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lineParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        lineParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        line.addView(checkBox, lineParams);
        return line;
    }
```

And somewhere inside `ListView` there's `setOnItemClickListener()`, which should intercept item clicking events. My problem that, whenever I try to add checkbox to item - I don't get any responces from my `ListView`. If I skip `CheckBox` or any other `Button` it works.

I am really stuck with this problem, I have tried all kind of Layouts, aligning, wrapping and so on - useless. Looks like `CheckBox` interferes `ListView` item click events.

Any ideas how to overcome?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

just add this line into the item views instead of listView itself

```
android:focusable="false"
```

check more detail about this from [Android custom ListView unable to click on items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1121192/760489)

Comment: It doesn't help! Any other options?

Comment: OK, I've figured - it works. I would need to put setFocusable(false) for item views instead of listView itself. Thanx!

Comment: It does work if setting focusable false on the view stealing the focus - in this case the check box or button.

Comment: If you have textview in each row then make sure `textIsSelectable` is set to `false`

Comment: In my Adapter, I set `btn.setFocusable(false)` which solves the problem. I think Android sets `focusable` to true after loading the XML.

Comment: Appears this solution doesn't work when ImageButton is used in the list item

Answer (score 19):

If you have ImageButtons inside the list item, you need to add:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to the root list item element [such as the root layout].

Then within each ImageButton in the list item, you need to add:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

This worked for me - but I was using ImageButtons, not the standard button.

Comment: PERFECT :-)
Thanks

Answer (score 13):

I have also faced the same issue I have tried to set `android:focusable="false"` to listview but it don't work then I add this to listview item.. like in my listview item I have uesed Toggle button which was creating problem, I add `android:focusable="false"` to Toggle button and listview on item click listener start work again

Answer (score 1):

Add following line to your listView

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
```

or make sure to set following lines to your layout text fields

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also had the problem of a Button in my ListView. Unfortunately just setting the focus to false for all objects in my Adapter did not work for me.

I now have a workaround.

In your Adapter create an OnClickListener for the button (or other clickable object) if you have not already done that. In that OnClickListener you call the OnItemClickListener yourself.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    mOnItemClickListener.setOnItemClick(mListView, v, vPos, vId);
}
```

It does mean that you will need to give your adapter access to both the parent ListView and the OnItemClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to write your on OnTouchEvent in your listview item and send the proper touchEvent to you child view , the button .

Answer (score 0):

Well i know none of the above solutions will work.I tried changing xml attributes but those does not work out, But i implemented it in a new fashion.
Here is how:

Create an *interface* `CheckBoxOnCheckListener` with method `onCheckBoxChecked` and pass needed parameters, implement interface `CheckBoxOnCheckListener` in your *activity* or *fragment* containing *listView*.

Next in your adapter, declare an `mListener` as `CheckBoxOnCheckListener`, and pass this as a parameter to Adapter's constructor from `fragment/activity` and cast it to `CheckBoxOnCheckListener` and assign to `mListener`.

Next set `mListener` as `itemView.onClick` or `CheckBox.onCheckCheckedListener` and `onCheckChanged` method call `mListener.onCheckBoxChecked`.

That's it. It will definitely work,it worked for me.
For code just pm.

Answer (score -6):

If you are using `ListView` in `Activity`, ensure you have setup `setOnItemClickListener()`

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(this); // if your activity implement OnItemClickListener
```