# How to have a checkbox inside of a listview, to have a listener outside adapter activity?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

So, I have menu items being displayed in `listview`, along with `checkboxes`, for the user to select which he likes. And I have an overhead cart icon which keeps track of no of checked items, by a function that is written in the adapter view.

```
My problem:
```

When I have implemented the cart increment function inside of `OnItemClick listener`, and then when I check a few items, it `doesn't get updated` unless I make a `click outside of checkbox` (anywhere else in the listview).

I have tried disabling descendant focusability and modifying focusability as per other SO answers. They haven't solved my issue.

My calling activity

```
adapter = new MenuAdapter(CreateOrder.this,itemslist);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                          selecteditems = adapter.getSelectedList();
                          Log.e("Selected Items",selecteditems.toString());
                          size = selecteditems.size();
                          qo.setText(String.valueOf(size));
                          Log.e("No of main items ",String.valueOf(size));


            }
        });
```

Comment: `When I have implemented the cart increment function inside of OnItemClick listener, and then when I check a few items, it doesn't get updated`. Of course not. You have no update code in the onClick of the checkboxes. There is no  qo.setText(....); there.

Comment: Is there a way to get the Onclick of checkboxes in Mainactivity?

Comment: You just put  qo.setText(....); there. If that is what you mean with 'icon'.

Comment: I dint get you. It doesnt enter the clickListener, if i check the checkbox. Even though it updates my linkedlist.

Comment: My god.. I asked you before if the checkbox listener  worked. You did not give an answer. And now it does not work. Well get it to work first. `Even though it updates my linkedlist` ?? How would that be possibke if onClick is not invoked?

Comment: You really dont understand my question. I have been trying so hard, but you cant.+

Comment: Yes i tried hard too to understand you as you can see. I spend already an hour.

Comment: Same here. But if it helps any its similiar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900913/onitemclicklistener-was-not-work-with-the-checkbox

Comment: A shame. Please reread your post. Nowhere you mention that your checkboxes onitemclick listeners do not work. You should have started with that. And only have posted that problem.

Comment: Have you even looked at the link i posted.

Comment: Yes. Thats why i blame you.

Comment: Ok. As per your request, i have removed my adapter class, If it further confuses people, to think my adapter's onclicklistener of checkbox is faulty.

Comment: ???? You said it did not work. So what do you expect people to think? And further i did not request to remove adapter code.

Comment: Well, you have misunderstood since long. Do you have the answer to my _real_ problem. Adapter code is not needed anyways.. For the problem i am facing

Answer (score 0):

> checkBoxState = new boolean[linkedList.size()];

You have that in getView(). So for every call of getView() you throw away the former.

In getView() you use checkBoxState[position] which then of course is undefined or null.

So take it out and put it in the constructor of your adapter and initialise it as you do with that int array.

By the way: why did not you tell that your checkboxes did not hold state during scrolling?

Comment: Thanks, but how does it solve my "checkbox not being listened" on clicking the listview problem.

Comment: Please first tell us if scrolling is ok now. If there were not enough menu items to let the user scroll then for a test add a lot more to test scrolling.

Comment: scrolling is fine for me. Actually it does displaying properly. But i cant dynamically access the count of checkboxes that has been clicked, in the listener. Even though the function inside the onclicklistener works

Comment: my problem is not with checkboxes and scrolling

Comment: Yes it was with that line in getView() checkboxes did not hold their state while scrolling. Impossible.

Comment: You aren't answering to my problem.

Comment: Yes i know. Before i can answer your question that scrolling problem should be solved. So please elaborate.

Comment: My checkbox when i click doesn't get a response as part of the ListView's OnItemClickListener.Although when i click anywhere else it gives me the log response. That's my issue

Comment: ??? That looks a quit different problem. If the user clicks a checkbox then the onClick() of holder.selectionBox.setOnClickListener() should be invoked. Are you telling that that is not happening?

Comment: that is happening in the adapter class. I want my response in MainActivity

Comment: ??? So the checkbox onclicklistener works? You could just say so. Further it is unclear what you mean with response.

Comment: `My checkbox when i click doesn't get a response ...` A response? Where are you talking about?

Comment: my returning linkedlist size is what i am looking for. It contains the no of checkboxes. And i want it, when i click the checkbox. Basically i want a checkbox listener in mainactivity

Comment: see my first code i posted." In the calling Activity." Thats where the trouble is.