# Android CheckBox inside ListView is not clickable while onItemClickedListener works

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, focus, android-checkbox

I'm using a CheckBox in the row item of my ListView. Is set the CheckBox to `android:focusable="false"`. So the OnItemClickListener for the ListView works correctly but the checkBox seems to be unclickable. How can i solve this?

in my custom arrayAdapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        FileHolder holder;
        if(v == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater();
            v = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new FileHolder();
            holder.isChecked = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            v.setTag(holder);
            holder.isChecked.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("common", "checked");
                }

            });
        }
}
```

in row_item.xml:

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        android:button="@drawable/checkbox"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="true"/>
```

**EDIT:** I tried to register an OnTouchListener, but onTouch() gets also not called.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413656/onitemclicklistener-doesnt-work-with-listview-item-containing-button

Comment: @nKn: please read the question or at least its title...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you should set focusable and focusableInTouchMode to false.
Try to set parent at null when you inflate layout

```
v = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null, false);
```

Hope it will help.

Also I think that if your list is long you will have an performance issue. It discourage to create `new OnClickListener(){}` on `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {}` if you list have a lot of row. Create on instance of listener set it for all row. You can use tag to determinate which view is click.

Comment: Yes you're right with the OnClickListener, thanks ! 
But, setting focusable to false is necessary otherwise the onItemClickListener would not work : http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html 
Unfortunately, inflating the row view without a rootView doesnt work better