# Share Intent destroying app after backclicked

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I have in my app a share function. I'm doing it like this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Share"));
```

It work's fine. But if i'm open it and not choose some app to share but just use backpressed to close the chooser dialog, i can't do anything in my app anymore. Each Button i click is doing nothing. First, if i'm open the chooser again an choose some app to share, the app works again.
Anybody know why it is so?
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Could you give us some more clue and code. We can't help you that much.

Comment: I don't know, what i should give you, because i don't know, what happens there. I just can say, that the Share function is called by onItemClick from a ListView. Then i just start the Intent and with a simple backclick in the chooserdialog i'm seeing the ListView again, but i can't click on any item. Just the shareitem works and the chooser will open again. If i'm choose then a app to share and will use the backclick again, then the app works fine. But if i'm just closing the chooserdialog, nothing works.

Comment: Does your ListView used a custom Adapter? Try playing with ListView's setFocusable() method.

Comment: Yes, i'm using a custom Adapter. What do you mean with setFocusable? That no item of the listview should be able to set focusable?

Comment: Take a read on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413656/onitemclicklistener-doesnt-work-with-listview-item-containing-button