# Can I use both of setOnItemClickListener and OnclickListner in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, imagebutton, onitemclicklistener

Is there a way to use both of `setOnItemClickListener` and `OnclickListner` in a ListView knowing that the List contains an `ImageButton` which will have `setOnclickListner`?

**Edit**

I use also `OnItemLongClickListner`
so:

1. I have something to do when I Click on the Item
2. I have something to do when I Long Click on the Item
3. and I have another thing to do when I click on the ImageButton that is in the Item

I hope that you can understand my problem and I know that I don't have a good English sorry

Comment: Of course, you can . By making `ImageButton`'s `onTouchEvent(...)` return `true`, you can get more help information after google-searching `android touch events`. wish you good luck.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work ... I have also `onItemLongClickListner`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved The problem by adding :

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to the root list item element [such as the root layout].

Then within each ImageButton in the list item, I add:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33187835/8716970)