# check boxes in listview not working

Tags: android, checkbox

I am using listview in which each item (of list view) has a checkbox and a textview.
when i am clivking on listview thw listener doesn't executes.

here is the code.

```
   ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    final CustomListArrayAdaptor aa = new CustomListArrayAdaptor(this,data1);
    lv.setAdapter(aa);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position, long arg3)
        {
            TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text);

            String s=tv.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Selected :"+s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
     });
```

It doesnt show the toast "Item Selected"   when clicked on any item.

Comment: If you write this way `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SimpleToast",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` , does it show up?

Comment: refer this link.it may helpfull... http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Can u show ur xml file where list is generated

Comment: post code of CustomListArrayAdaptor class.

Comment: Ur code is correct.i tried.its working for me.attach ur another files also.then we can try to solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained here

[Android custom ListView unable to click on items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121192/android-custom-listview-unable-to-click-on-items),

the click listener only works if no other view is focusable. Setting your CheckBox to focusable="false" should do the trick for you

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code is correct. Upload the other files code also.
As much I know this could be the problem of focus.Add (android:focusable="false")
if you are defining the check box in xml file or for the java code use the method myCheckBox.setFocusable(false).