# android layout cannot be changed in mapView

Tags: android, maps, imageview, android-mapview

I am using this https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons#readme project such that when a user clicks on a hotspot on the map a balloon with its info is inflated, my task is to add a button to that balloon so that when a user clicks on the button, an image of this hotspot will appear taking all the screen and it will have a button to close the image and go back to the old view.

I figured out how to add a button to the balloon, but the problem is I cant make its onclick action to change the layout to a new one with only an ImageView...what I could get was only the inflated balloon and next to it a small image which is not what I want

I would really appreciate any help
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use it a year ago, I remember that you have to put the button on the XML of the bubble and on the class that inflates de bubble you have to put the onClicklistener.

You can also try to on xml put the parameter "onclick="buttonPressed"" and when it's inflated you write the method public void buttonPressed(View v) {}.

If all this doesn't work try to set on XML on the bubble properties android:focusable="false"

It could be the same problem as this: [Android custom ListView unable to click on items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121192/android-custom-listview-unable-to-click-on-items)